# Simulate click on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to simulate a click on a element that I appended in.

Example:

```
var html = "<a data-fancybox data-src="#item52" id="fancy52" href="javascript:;">show</a>";

$("#places").append(html);
```

appended to:

```
<div id="places"></div>
```

Then to simulate a click I do the following:

```
$("#fancy52").click ();
```

But this doesn't work.  My only guess is because the content was added dynamically.

How can I simulate a click on this dynamic element?

Comment: With an anchor element, the jQuery `.click()` will trigger handlers bound to the element but won't trigger the default anchor click navigation behaviour. Try calling the DOM `.click()` method instead: `$("#fancy52")[0].click()`. (Also, the code shown has syntax errors on the first ilne, but I assume your real code doesn't have that problem or the anchor wouldn't be added to your page.)

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your snippet works fine, you just have to fix syntax error - you have mixed `"` in your string. See this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWGMvR?editors=1010 By adding `data-fancybox` attribute, click event is handled using event delegation .

Answer (score 0):

try to use jquery Function  live ,

```
$( "a.offsite" ).live( "click", function() {
alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+ });
```

});

Comment: OP is trying to trigger a click on the element, not bind a click handler to it. (Also, `.live()` is *way* out of date and was removed from jQuery in v1.9; you should be using `.on()`.)

Comment: yeah !!!. Thanks Bro